# Paginate an array of list items

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

I'm having a bit of trouble add some pagination to this page. The objective is to only have 10 list items show up at a time on every page. I have have to add an event to the buttons so when they are click they show the corresponding items.

Here is what I have so far in this codepen
http://codepen.io/temovargas/pen/mAqjaA

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="page-header cf">
          <h2>Students</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="student-list">
                <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/67.jpg">
                <h3>iboya vat</h3>
                <span class="email">iboya.vat@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg">
                <h3>aapo niskanen</h3>
                <span class="email">aapo.niskanen@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/34.jpg">
                <h3>phillip cox</h3>
                <span class="email">phillip.cox@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/11/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/38.jpg">
                <h3>zilda moreira</h3>
                <span class="email">zilda.moreira@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/23.jpg">
                <h3>lilou le gall</h3>
                <span class="email">lilou.le gall@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/16/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/94.jpg">
                <h3>lucy hall</h3>
                <span class="email">lucy.hall@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/11/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/24.jpg">
                <h3>mark colin</h3>
                <span class="email">mark.colin@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/14/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/14.jpg">
                <h3>sara alves</h3>
                <span class="email">sara.alves@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/19/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>ramon macrae</h3>
                <span class="email">ramon.macrae@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/13/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/15.jpg">
                <h3>connor taylor</h3>
                <span class="email">connor.taylor@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/18/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/11.jpg">
                <h3>aymeric morel</h3>
                <span class="email">aymeric.morel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>lorenz otto</h3>
                <span class="email">lorenz.otto@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/11/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/29.jpg">
                <h3>karl williamson</h3>
                <span class="email">karl.williamson@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/12/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/34.jpg">
                <h3>ouassim heering</h3>
                <span class="email">ouassim.heering@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/18/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>roberto molina</h3>
                <span class="email">roberto.molina@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/28.jpg">
                <h3>jordan hubert</h3>
                <span class="email">jordan.hubert@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/29.jpg">
                <h3>melvin baker</h3>
                <span class="email">melvin.baker@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/18/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/26.jpg">
                <h3>everett gordon</h3>
                <span class="email">everett.gordon@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/82.jpg">
                <h3>aiden ma</h3>
                <span class="email">aiden.ma@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/18/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/62.jpg">
                <h3>florent gerard</h3>
                <span class="email">florent.gerard@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/12/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/96.jpg">
                <h3>amber chen</h3>
                <span class="email">amber.chen@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/12/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/9.jpg">
                <h3>alexandra davies</h3>
                <span class="email">alexandra.davies@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/11/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/57.jpg">
                <h3>sergio cole</h3>
                <span class="email">sergio.cole@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/98.jpg">
                <h3>edgar dixon</h3>
                <span class="email">edgar.dixon@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/94.jpg">
                <h3>kirk myers</h3>
                <span class="email">kirk.myers@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/28.jpg">
                <h3>ani hesseling</h3>
                <span class="email">ani.hesseling@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 08/14/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/24.jpg">
                <h3>victoire bonnet</h3>
                <span class="email">victoire.bonnet@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/13/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/44.jpg">
                <h3>marcos morales</h3>
                <span class="email">marcos.morales@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/12/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg">
                <h3>nils neumann</h3>
                <span class="email">nils.neumann@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/11/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/86.jpg">
                <h3>emily harrison</h3>
                <span class="email">emily.harrison@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/18/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>matthew fortin</h3>
                <span class="email">matthew.fortin@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/18/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/32.jpg">
                <h3>charlotte steward</h3>
                <span class="email">charlotte.steward@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/18/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/3.jpg">
                <h3>marceau rodriguez</h3>
                <span class="email">marceau.rodriguez@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/13/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>hudson anderson</h3>
                <span class="email">hudson.anderson@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>

        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/33.jpg">
                <h3>warren phillips</h3>
                <span class="email">warren.phillips@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/11/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>leo niva</h3>
                <span class="email">leo.niva@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/14/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/3.jpg">
                <h3>hani prevoo</h3>
                <span class="email">hani.prevoo@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/11/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/79.jpg">
                <h3>veronica rodriguez</h3>
                <span class="email">veronica.rodriguez@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/17/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>ginestal das neves</h3>
                <span class="email">ginestal.das neves@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/19/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/63.jpg">
                <h3>devon barnes</h3>
                <span class="email">devon.barnes@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/19/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/55.jpg">
                <h3>brennan pierce</h3>
                <span class="email">brennan.pierce@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/15/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/35.jpg">
                <h3>zachary singh</h3>
                <span class="email">zachary.singh@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/19/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/35.jpg">
                <h3>arlo harris</h3>
                <span class="email">arlo.harris@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/60.jpg">
                <h3>hannah ginnish</h3>
                <span class="email">hannah.ginnish@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/17/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/95.jpg">
                <h3>goos brunt</h3>
                <span class="email">goos.brunt@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>eduard riedel</h3>
                <span class="email">eduard.riedel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/42.jpg">
                <h3>geesken jekel</h3>
                <span class="email">geesken.jekel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/12/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/54.jpg">
                <h3>dolores ryan</h3>
                <span class="email">dolores.ryan@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>steven rogers</h3>
                <span class="email">steven.rogers@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/18/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/63.jpg">
                <h3>virgulino silva</h3>
                <span class="email">virgulino.silva@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/18/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/11.jpg">
                <h3>lucile bertrand</h3>
                <span class="email">lucile.bertrand@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/10.jpg">
                <h3>elsa lahti</h3>
                <span class="email">elsa.lahti@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 04/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/12.jpg">
                <h3>soline leclercq</h3>
                <span class="email">soline.leclercq@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/12/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/89.jpg">
                <h3>henri kruse</h3>
                <span class="email">henri.kruse@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/14/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
var pageSize = 10;
var items = $('.student-item');
var currentPage;

function initPage(){
    // adds search bar
    $("h2").after('<div class="student-search page-header"><input type="text" id="searchForm" placeholder="Search for students..."><button>Search</button></div>'); //insert search bar and button on page load.
    // hides all items
    items.hide();
    // shows 10 items
    items.slice(0,10).show();
}



// builds the html for the buttons
function addBtns(){
    var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(items.length / pageSize);

    var $buttonHtml = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
    // adds button
    for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
        $buttonHtml += '<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>';
    }
    $buttonHtml += '</ul></div>';
    // appends buttons to the html
    $('.page').append($buttonHtml);

    // gives first item active class
    $('.pagination li a:first').addClass('active');

}

addBtns();
initPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a plugin such as DataTables or Jquery.paginate?
I've found home-brewing this kind of element exposes too many user cases to have to deal with later on. In my experience, a developed plugin will have grown to handle edge cases, etc.